# Smooth toggle in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using some simple jQuery to animate a toggle button. The toggle works, however, no matter how I try changing values, I cannot seem to change the speed or smoothness of the animation.

I have looked at different methods and tried changing the values within the .sliderUp section, it just isn't working for me.

The code I am using is:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("a.toggle").click(function(){
        if ($("nav ul").hasClass("expanded")) {
            $("nav ul.expanded").removeClass("expanded").slideUp(250);
            $(this).removeClass("open");
        } else {
            $("nav ul").addClass("expanded").slideDown(250);
            $(this).addClass("open");
        }
    });
});
```

-

```
<nav>
    <a href="#" class="toggle">Toggle Menu</a>
    <ul>
        <li>Menu Item</li>
        <li>Menu Item</li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

-

```
nav {
    width: 100%;

    ul {
        display: none;
        width: 100%;

        &.expanded {
            display: block;
        }
    }

    .toggle {
        display: block !important;
    }
}
```

Comment: can't you use slideToggle?

Comment: Try css3 `transition`, for instance `transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use **slideToggle**

Syntax

```
$(selector).slideToggle(speed,callback);
```

Here the optional **speed parameter** can take the following values: "slow", "fast", **milliseconds**.

So i think you need to put more time to get smooth animation.

Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("a.toggle").click(function(){
    $("nav ul").slideToggle(1500);
    $(this).toggleClass("open");
  });
});
```

Here is the working jsfiddle:https://jsfiddle.net/88bm4x6z/1/

Comment: Thank you, this was just what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

If any of you still not been able to slide smoothly, just set `transition: none;`. if you'r using it in your parent item or child, I stuck in it for 3 hours. Then I just set it to none, it worked.