# Fluid Toggle Transition

Tags: jquery, html, css

Atm I'm toggling the side menu with `block` or `none`.

But it's very strange and I wanted something more fluid. Is there a way to make a transaction between block and none?

```
$('#sidebar').css('display', 'none');
```

Comment: Tried `slideUp()`, `slideToggle()`, or using `animate()` yourself??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Smooth Toggle - Jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43451782/smooth-toggle-jquery)

Comment: provide html of  #sidebar

Answer (score 0):

try this.it will give smooth transition

```
 va i=0;
$('#sidebar').click(function(){
   i++;
   if(i%2==0){
    $('#sidebar').animate({width:0});
    $('#sidebar').animate({left:0});
}
else{
    $('#sidebar').animate({width:200});
    $('#sidebar').animate({left:200});
}
})
```

P.S

```
  $('#sidebar').animate({width:200});
        $('#sidebar').animate({left:200});
```

give your side bar width in above value

Comment: It won't any more as this implementation of `toggle()` was deprecated in 1.8 and removed in 1.9: http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/. Either way, using CSS by toggling a class would be a better approach.